# Make a float using integers

Tags: arduino-uno, variables, float

I want to make a floating point number that has only one decimal point.
I have separate integers for both side.
Ex:

`int n1 = 8;`

`int n2 = 2;`

I want to make 8.2 as float value using separate integers.
Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems too simple:

```
float x = n1 + n2 * 0.1;
```

Is there a trick?

**Edit**: The method proposed by Michel Keijzers, namely

```
float x = n1 + n2 / 10.0;
```

(I removed the redundant casts) can be slightly more accurate, but takes
longer to compute, because division is significantly slower than
multiplication on the Uno. Computing `n2/10.0` always yields the
correctly rounded result, namely the float that best approximates the
exact mathematical result. On the other hand, `n2*0.1` involves *two*
rounding operations: one at compile time, in the representation of 0.1
(which is not an exact float), another at run time, which rounds the
result of the multiplication. If `n2` is between 0 and 8, you end up
getting the correctly rounded result anyway, just as with `n2/10.0`.
However, if `n2` is 9, then

- `n2*0.1` yields 0.900000035762786865234375 (error ≈ 3.6e-8)
- `n2/10.0` yields 0.89999997615814208984375 (error ≈ -2.4e-8)

The former carries a rounding error 1.5 larger than the latter.

Answer (score 2):

```
float x = (float) n1 + (float) (n2 / 10.0);
```

This works only if the value of n2 has 1 digit. Otherwise the following make it smaller until n2 gets below 1.0:

```
float x = (float) n1;

float f2 = (float) n2;
while (f2 >= 1.0)
{
   f2 /= 10.0;
}
x = n1 + f2;
```